# Rails/Ruby asking for "@localhost" password on deploy:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm  still pretty new to this. I've been trying to get this software 
running: https://github.com/r888888888/danbooru
But I'm stuck on the deployment step . After trying to deploy, it asks me to login to the user "@localhost", and rejects every password I try. I feel like there should be a name before "@localhost", but I'm a bit lost. I've been able to google and figure out everything else up to this point.

Here's a picture of what I'm seeing: imgur.com/ONp69.png

and also the text:

```
   danbooru@teemo:~/danbooru$ bundle exec cap development deploy:setup
 [9951bc77] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ] on localhost
 [9951bc77] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ]
@localhost's password:
@localhost's password:
@localhost's password:
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host localhost: Authentication failed for user @localhost
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user @localhost
Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano's actually prompting you to log in to a nameless user; "localhost" refers to your computer. You can see on Github that the [production](https://github.com/r888888888/danbooru/blob/master/config/deploy/production.rb) and [staging](https://github.com/r888888888/danbooru/blob/master/config/deploy/staging.rb) deployment configuration includes a `:user` setting, but that's not defined [in the development config](https://github.com/r888888888/danbooru/blob/master/config/deploy/development.rb).

The development environment is normally used by programmers making changes to the code; if you're trying to deploy the site so it's publicly available, then you should edit your copy of the [production configuration](https://github.com/r888888888/danbooru/blob/master/config/deploy/production.rb) to refer to a user account & server you have access to, then run `bundle exec cap production deploy`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so well, I added a line referring to a user but that seemed to cause more problems, and things got weird. It started to copy the lines twice over, I'll attach a picture of what it looks like.

imgur.com/UHsA0Ys.png

I emailed the dev about this too. I'll keep dabbling around to see if I can fix it until then though.

Comment: also I should add, I'm doing this all through a VPS (using linode), so the localhost would be the VPS right? Not the computer I'm using to control it from?